# Script to notify the changes in package version

Tags: python, linux, shell

i have list of builds  in particular path /file/proj/
inside that proj the builds directory list will be like

```
3.7.0.0.121/         
4.2.0.0.200-GA/ 
4.2.0.0.200/
4.2.1.0.54-GA/   
4.2.1.0.54/  
4.3.0.0.5-GA/
4.3.0.0.5/  
4.4.0.164.403/   
4.4.0.165.404/
```

here 4.2.1.0.54-GA/ is my latest stable version and 4.4.0.165.404/ is the latest frequent release version .

Inside the 4.2.1.0.54-GA/ build i have files like

1. proj_4.3.0_App_Update.zip
2. proj_4.3.0_App_Update_UI.zip
3. dfd.txt

Inside the 4.4.0.165.404/ build i have files like

1. proj_4.4.0_App_Update.zip
2. proj_4.4.0_App_Update_UI.zip
3. dfd.txt

here i need to copy and  unzip the particular file proj_4.3.0_App_Update.zip inside both the stable and frequent release version  in the folder like /workspace/build
after unzip inside the particular path (/build/pack/x86_64/) in both stable and frequent release version i have list of packages like

```
apac_4.3.rpm
buil_3.4.rpm
ssnjx_3.3.rpm
```

so i need to compare both stable and frequent release  rpm files version and list what are the new versions are updated compared to stable release

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad; it's not clear if you're asking each, or only some, of the following questions:

1. How to "automatically" download the latest version of a zip file.
2. How to extract only the files you want to compare from those two files.
3. How to compare specific subdirectories in two different folders.
4. How to display the differences.

The following script tries to answer each of the questions, and explain each step; hopefully it helps:

```sh
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    # exit script immediately on error
    set -e 

    # Example zip files, adjust for your use case
    BASE_URL=https://github.com/johnweldon/tiny-profile/archive
    LATEST=0.1.9
    STABLE=0.1.8

    # Create temporary directory to extract into
    TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
    echo "created ${TEMPDIR}"

    # Clean up temporary directory when done.  Comment the next line if you
    # want to keep the directory
    trap "rm -rf $TEMPDIR && echo \"deleted ${TEMPDIR}\"" EXIT


    # Download and extract only files needed from LATEST into $TEMPDIR/latest
    ( cd $TEMPDIR;
      curl -L -o latest.zip "$BASE_URL/v$LATEST.zip" && \
      unzip latest.zip */bin/* */.vim/ftplugin/* -d latest) >/dev/null 2>&1
    # Download and extract only files needed from STABLE  into $TEMPDIR/stable
    ( cd $TEMPDIR; 
      curl -L -o stable.zip "$BASE_URL/v$STABLE.zip" && \
      unzip stable.zip */bin/* */.vim/ftplugin/* -d stable) >/dev/null 2>&1

    echo -e "\nBEGIN DIFFERENCES:\n------------------\n\n"
    (cd $TEMPDIR;
      diff -r stable/tiny-profile-$STABLE/ latest/tiny-profile-$LATEST/ || true)
    echo -e "\n\n---------------\nEND DIFFERENCES\n"
```

Comment: Hi John thanks for your reply

Comment: This example script can be modified to address your use case.  If you have specific questions ask them individually, and specifically rather than generally and implied.  Best wishes: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: but here Latest and stable version may vary or update to new version on daily basis, so what should do in these scenarios?